# Terminate Scrapy crawl manually

Tags: python, scrapy

When trying to run a spider in Scrapy, after having run it before with other parameters, I get this error message:

```
crawl: error: running 'scrapy crawl' with more than one spider is no longer supported
```

I interpret this as the first crawl still running in some sense. I am looking for some way to terminate all running Scrapy processes, in order to start clean with a new crawl.

Comment: no spider was started, you'll have to start each of them individually

Comment: @eLRuLL Sorry, I don't see what you mean. The first time I gave the 'scrapy crawl ...'-command, the scraping started. After closing Terminal and giving the command again, I got the error message described above.

Comment: No way the same command will output differently, maybe use a different terminal, but you'll have to explain more to help you

Comment: PLease publish the actual command line so we can review it and help

Answer (score 0):

I use an incremented number to break the loop when I'm testing

```
 def parse(self, response):
     i = 0
     for sel in response.xpath('something'):
         if i > 2:
             break
         #something
         i += 1
         #something
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using multiple command line parameters in wrong way. Simply `scrapy crawl <spidername>` will work fine. You may missed any specifiers if you are trying to use multiple command line arguments.

For terminating all running Scrapy processes, in Linux OS you can simply find out and kill all Scrapy processes by using the following command in Linux terminal

```
pkill scrapy
```

Please use [Windows PsKill](https://ss64.com/nt/pskill.html) for Windows OS.