# Terminate scrapy and keep output file

Tags: python, scrapy

Made a coding mistake, and my spdier is likely running in a loop. How can I terminate the spider and save the output json file. My experience was forced termination will lead to no output file being saved. Any suggestion?

Can `pkill` save the output file? 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46727707/7870384

Comment: what is your code? is it possible to change your code instead of trying to terminate it?

Comment: @bunbun It is scrapying around 250,000 webpages. Don't want run it all over again. According to [this](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2913), probably due to `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` setting.

Answer (score 4):

Just send *one* `SIGTERM` signal and scrapy will terminate gracefully once downloader queue is empty.
If you send *two* `SIGTERM` signals scrapy will terminate forcefully and ignore downloader queue or anything else that is waiting in `Twisted` engine.
If you send `SIGKILL` the process will be dumped and closed without giving scrapy a chance to do anything

In other words just send `kill <pid>` (uses `SIGTERM` signal by default) if you send `kill -9 <pid>` it will use `SIGKILL` signal

Comment: great. One must be patient sometimes!